# If input greater than 60 characters use textarea instead

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to count the characters in an input using Angular
 then if character count greater than 60 use a textarea instead.

I thought I might be able to get away with doing this in my script:

```
//my initial display value
$scope.display = "this is a particularly long string that i'm using to test this functionality";
//storing the length of the display variable
$scope.charCount = $scope.display.length;
```

I then use the `charCount` variable in an `ng-if` condition to determine whether or not to use an `input` **or** `textarea`.

```
<div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" ng-controller="controller" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount <= 60">
    <input
        type="text"
        ng-bind="display"
        ng-value="display">
</div>
<div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" ng-controller="controller" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount > 60">
    <textarea
        type="text" 
        ng-bind="display"
        ng-value="display" >
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Strangely this does not render either element. I'm fairly new to Angular so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Why don't you use a textarea in all cases, and if the length is more than 60, you add a row to your textarea ?

Comment: It's working . see here. https://plnkr.co/edit/Xq2D8brgN3WxMv10J6pm?p=preview

Comment: @Satpal because i need to reference the same controller on both conditions. Im not an Angular expert so if you can suggest a better way of doing id appreciate it.

Comment: `ng-controller` will create a new scope so 2 instances will never be same

Comment: @Satpal thanks for the advice, it all helps in the long run when learning a new language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your controller for use parent scope.

You can use it like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount => 60">
    <input
        type="text"
        ng-bind="display"
        ng-value="display">
</div>
<div data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount < 60">
    <textarea
        type="text" 
        ng-bind="display"
        ng-value="display" >
    </textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it, i hadnt realised you couldnt reference the same controller twice. Cheers

Comment: @MasterYoda Have nice day master :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `ng-controller="controller"` from both element. it should work.

```
 <div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount <= 60">
    <input type="text" ng-bind="display" ng-value="display">
  </div>
  <div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount > 60">
    <textarea type="text" ng-bind="display" ng-value="display">
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xq2D8brgN3WxMv10J6pm?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your suggestion really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `ng-controller` and put the conditions for input/textarea within the scope of this controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.display = "this is a particularly long string that i'm using   to test this functionality";
 //storing the length of the display variable
 $scope.charCount = $scope.display.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount <= 60">
        <input type="text" ng-bind="display" ng-value="display"> </div>
    <div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-if="charCount > 60">
        <textarea type="text" ng-bind="display" ng-value="display"> </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers Vivz i hadn't realised you only needed to reference the controller once.

Comment: @MasterYoda Yeah declaring it once and putting all the required code within the scope of this controller will work just fine. Anyways glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

some mistakes

- you made here in you are using `ng-bind` for input fields, Which is
  wrong way to use **[ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)**
- remove form divs `ng-controller="controller"`

Use [**ng-show**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and instead of **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)** use `display.length` in your view as there are some boundations to use `ng-if`

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('app', []);

      app.controller('OneController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.display = 'ssss'
        $scope.changedInput = function (argument) {

        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="OneController">
    {{aa}}

    <div data-custom-focus="true" ng-show="display.length <= 60">
        <input
        type="text" ng-change = "changedInput()"
        ng-model="display"
        ng-value="display">
    </div>
    <div data-custom-focus="true" ng-show="display.length > 60">
        <textarea ng-change = "changedInput()"
        type="text" 
        ng-model="display"
        ng-value="display" >
    </textarea>
</div>
Count: {{display.length}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not make any diff here. we can use `charCount` as well.

Comment: @AmitKumar thats my bad. Now check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-show="display.length <= 60">
<input
    type="text"
    ng-bind="display"
    ng-value="display">
</div>
  <div id="ctrl_{{field.id}}" data-custom-focus="true" ng-show="display.length > 60">

<textarea
    type="text" 
    ng-bind="display"
    ng-value="display" >
</textarea>
```